# como puedo enviar los resultados del select por phpmailer

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmailer

lo que quiero hacer es que me envié todos los resultado del select de la tabla tb_matriculado por phpmailer pero cuando lo hago solo me envía el ultimo resultado de la tabla

```html
$sql = $this->conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM tb_matriculado");
            $sql->execute();
            $resultado = $sql->fetchAll();
            foreach($resultado as $fila) {
                $mensaje = "<tr><td>".$fila['apellidos']."</td> <td>".$fila['nombre']."</td><td>".$fila['dni']."</td><td>".$fila['cel']."</td><td>".$fila['correo']."</td><td>".$fila['carrera']."</td><td>".$fila['semestre']."</td><td>".$fila['fecha']."</td><td>";
            }
            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->isSMTP();
            $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
            $mail->Port = 587;
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail->Username = "prueba@gmail.com";
            $mail->Password = "HeLlOWoRlD";
            $mail->setFrom('prueba@gmail.com', 'De: ');
            $mail->addReplyTo('prueba@gmail.com', 'Responder a: ');
            $mail->addAddress('borit80638@prekab.net', 'Para: ');
            $mail->Subject = 'Mensaje desde PHP';
            $mail->Body = $mensaje;
            $mail->isHTML(true);
            if (!$mail->send()) 
            {
                echo "NO SE PUDO ENVIAR";
            } else 
            {
                echo "SE ENVIO A SU CORREO";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

1.- Lo que te recomiendo es que en esta linea de codigo:

```
$mensaje = "<tr><td>".$fila['apellidos']."</td> <td>".$fila['nombre']."</td><td>".$fila['dni']."</td><td>".$fila['cel']."</td><td>".$fila['correo']."</td><td>".$fila['carrera']."</td><td>".$fila['semestre']."</td><td>".$fila['fecha']."</td><td>";
```

Concatenes con `.=` ya que en cada recorrido de tu `foreach` estas reasignando el valor de esa variable. Por lo que lo correcto seria poner:

```
$mensaje .= "<tr><td>".$fila['apellidos']."</td> <td>".$fila['nombre']."</td><td>".$fila['dni']."</td><td>".$fila['cel']."</td><td>".$fila['correo']."</td><td>".$fila['carrera']."</td><td>".$fila['semestre']."</td><td>".$fila['fecha']."</td><td>";
```

Tal vez te interese leer mas al respecto:

[Operadores para strings](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.string.php)